# How to select row in Mac in MC and cut one?

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor, mc

I've installed to Mac a Midnight Commander (I did not find better terminal text editor).
I tried edit file - it works.
I tried select row to cut - I can't...

So question is `How to select row in Mac in MC and cut one?`

Comment: If shift+arrows don't work try to use shift+mouse. Does it work?

Comment: Mouse is able to select area, but i wanted to use only keyboard. Anyway I can't cut or copy selected area in MC on Mac.

Comment: Ctrl+Insert, Ctrl+Delete, Shift+Delete — do the work?

Comment: @phd for Mac (Mac does not have `Insert` key)? If you know how to emulate it, please write also, and operation which should run after that.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/169164